Does lucrative property leads to a price increase of real estate?
Good day to everybody,
I have an intuition that lucrative property (by that, I mean buying real estate goods in order to rent them and make profit, however small or big) in it's ensemble necessarily leads to an increase in real estates buying prices. But I'm not able to justify it, nor am I able to quantify what's the ratio between this effect, and other whatever they might be.
I have very poor knowledge about economics and maybe even my postulate is wrong. If you could enlighten me, I would be much grateful.
